# In Rails, how would I include a section of a page only if the rest of the page doesn't match a certain regexp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adsense

We have a site with a lot of user-generated content, and we'd like to show Google ads on it.  Some of the content is such that we mustn't show the ads on pages containing that content, or else the whole site gets banned.  We've come up with a regexp which we think will match all the offending content.

So, three approaches come to mind:

1. Render the page once without the ad section, and then insert the ad section into it if it's clean
2. Render the page as normal, and do the insertion in client-side javascript
3. Render the page above the ad section, capturing only the parts of the page that change; make sure there are no changing parts afterwards.  Only show the ads if the captured text is clean, and make sure the unchanging, uncaptured parts are well-vetted in advance.

The first one seems like it might delay the page rendering for too long; the second seems like it might delay showing the ads too long; and the third seems too fragile.  Is there a better approach?  If not, which one is the best solution of the three?

Answer (score 2):

If you're storing the user-generated content in a database, then you should be able to add the decision about whether the content is 'clean' or not within your model definition.

Then, your views could include or exclude the relevant advertising tags based on the value of the current object's cleanliness, for example:

```
<%= @article.body %>
<% if @article.clean? %>
  <= render :partial => 'ads/google' %>
<% end %>
```

If your page content is made up of multiple objects and you need to check all their possible output text, that complicates things a little, but it's not unattainable.

At the moment, though, it sounds like you're attempting to put all this business logic solely at the client/javascript layer. As you suggest, this can be pretty slow, and unreliable. It's also really hard to test. Moving the rules into your business models will allow you to test them, and ensure that they don't break as you work on ways to make them run as quickly as possible.

Comment: I'd like to do that, but we have frequent uses of cached Cells which may contain unclean content, so it's hard to determine cleanliness in advance like that.